# ReferenceError: Headers is not defined

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, netlify

I'm building an api using express netlify-lambda and firebase, but stumbled into this error. When I visit the url to get the data I get a ReferenceError: Headers is not defined. So I've figured out it was a problem with firebase, but I couldn't find the correct information I was looking for.

So this is what I'm trying to do, here are my imports:

```
const express = require('express');
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const firebase = require("../resources/firebase"); // Import firebase config file
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const {doc, getDoc } = require("firebase/firestore");
```

Here's the part of the router:

```
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/memes', async (req, res) => {
    const apiKey = req.query.key;

    const hashedApiKey = hashAPIKey(apiKey)

    // This is where i get the error
    const customerId = await getDoc(doc(firebase.db, "apiKeys", hashedApiKey));
    const customer = await getDoc(doc(firebase.db, "customers", customerId.toString()));
    
    if (!customer.active) {
        res.sendStatus(403)
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write('<h1>Hello from Express.js!</h1>');
        res.end();
    }
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/.netlify/functions/index', router);

module.exports = app;
module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

After running the command to startup netlify-lambda `"start": "netlify-lambda serve src"` and then visiting this url `http://localhost:9000/.netlify/functions/index/memes?key=bla` the error will be thrown and netlify-lambda will shutdown.

I'm guessing I need to send headers with a Bearer token to firebase before trying to get a document. I could also be completely wrong. Anyway if anyone knows what to do please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Keygun2k1, was my answer helpful ?

Comment: Hey @JoseGermanPerezSanchez thanks for replying this was indeed the solution. Marked it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send headers with a Bearer token to firebase before trying to get a document, Bearer Token must be added to Firebase via the Authorization header.
The header is usually formatted as follows:

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

This is documented in the [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework: Bearer Token Usage, section 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1).
Of course, your backend should parse the same format.

Keep in mind that the Headers constructor isn't available in the node.js environment. You'll need to include it from the node-fetch package, just like fetch. To get it from the fetch function, you can use a destructuring assignment.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch'); const { Headers } = fetch;
```

To create a new instance, utilize the property directly.

```
let headers = new fetch.Headers();
```

For further information, see [the node-fetch documentation](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#class-headers).

Comment: Sorry for not replying, but this was indeed the solve I needed. I find it strange that this ```Headers``` is used in the build while not using it in the code. Maybe Firebase uses it in their package?